# How can I check whether the script started with cron job is completed?

Tags: python, cron, cron-task

I start a script and I want to start second one immediately after the first one is completed successfully?

The problem here is that this script can take 10min or 10hours according to specific cases and I do not want to fix the start of the second script.
Also, I am using python to develop the script, so if you can provide me a solution with python control on the cron it will be OK.

Thank you,

Comment: `grep scriptname /var/log/syslog` may be helps?

Comment: Why don't you do `<cron syntax> /script1.py && /script2.py` so that if the first one ends successfully, the second one will start.

Comment: A small addition to @fedorqui: make sure that last line of a successful script1.py is sys.exit(0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lock file to indicate that the first script is still running.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [atexit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html) module. As part of first script, you could register the function. From the registered function at exit, you could call the second script or execute the second script using system.

```
import atexit
def at_exit():
    print 'invoke the second script'
atexit.register(at_exit)
```